# HttpWebRequest GET ProtocolViolationException WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, windows-phone

I need to make a GET request with headers (this is the requeriment) but i am receiving the Protocol Violation Exception.

This is my code:

```
      System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri("http://54.219.33.208:8080/wsrewards/consultaEstatusRewards");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers["idUser"] = user;
        request.Headers["auth"] = autho;
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestStreamCallbackConsultaEstatusRewards), request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN on BeginGetRequestStream says: *Begins an asynchronous request for a Stream object to use to write data.*

With GET method, you can't write any data to request. BeginGetRequestStream is only for e.g. POST and PUT methods.

You should probably replace your `BeginGetRequestStream` with `BeginGetResponse`, and then call `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()` method of the response object to access the response stream.

Comment: And one more thing. You should consider using async-await for that kind of code. Those async callbacks are much harder to debug compared to e.g. `var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();`